# Is the following piece of code using FILE*, ftell, fwrite, and fflush thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

In the below code, my function writes a data entry to disk, and is supposed to return the offset into the file at which the entry is recorded. However, when running the code in multiple threads, I'm finding that occasionally, this value is not accurate. Are there any thread safety problems with this code?

```
// global file descriptor to current data file, shared amongst many threads
FILE* current_fp;
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
...

int main()
{
    ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);

    current_fp = fopen(data_file, "ab");
    if (current_fp == NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unable to open file %s: %s\n", __func__, data_file, strerror_r(errno, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf)));
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&ldb_mutex);
       return -1;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);  

    return 0;
}

// write a data entry, and return the offset at which it will be stored
// I'm having an issue where it seems like *occasionally* the offset returned is not
// really the offset at which the entry was stored, with multiple threads
long write_log_entry(data_entry_t* entry)
{
   int num_written; 
   long offset; // offset at which entry will be written

   pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);

   // get the next offset in the file, which is where I expect
   // the entry to be stored
   offset = ftell(current_fp);
   if (offset == -1)
   {
      error();
   }

   // an example -- the real code writes a bunch of data members of entry
   int num_written = fwrite(entry, sizeof(data_entry_t), 1, current_fp);
   if (num_written != 1) 
   {
       error();
   }

   fflush(current_fp);

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);

   return offset; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: It's difficult to track down in a debugger because the issue only happens very rarely (say, 1 in 100k entries written).

Comment: @user1494899 What are the incorrect values that you are getting? Are they off by a few bytes, or do you get complete garbage (e.g. negative values or values past the end of the file)?

Comment: The incorrect values are other actual intact entries. i.e., the entries are a fixed size of 31 bytes; every incorrect value is also a multiple of 31 (which leads me to incorrectly referencing some other entry).

Comment: Is the mutex properly initialized somewhere ? And are you very certain no code uses the FILE* outside the mutex ? Also, we can't really understand what the incorrect values are or what you mean with intact entries in your last comment..

Comment: Yes, the mutex is properly initialized. The only code that uses the FILE* is shown.

Comment: Well, it calls error() without unlocking the mutex, but that's probably not relevant?

Comment: Nah - I just wrote error() there for simplicity. No errors occur (my real error handling logs errors).

Comment: If many threads open the file, what is the implication of continually overwriting FILE* current_fp?  Are you not leaking file handles?

Comment: Helgrind often helps to automatically detect synchronization related bugs. Compile with debug symbols and try: valgrind --tool=helgrind ./your_executable

Comment: I suspect that, due to the sharing of the current_fp pointer, some threads are using different file descriptors than others and confusing the file system.  This is especially likely to happen if threads are being continually created and destroyed, possibly leaking more and more inconsistent file descriptors :(

Comment: I do not see any obvious errors. The non-obvious errors could be results of not checking return values of fflush() and pthread_mutex_lock(). The latter could fail for instance if you also use this mutex for some other purpose and it's not recursive and you already locked it in the same thread. Also you should ensure that you don't read from this file in parallel (even under mutex), otherwise see the answer from Jan Wrobel below (regarding mixing output and input).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is related to the behaviour described in the fopen manual:

'Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output
 and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this  condition  is  not met, then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other
 than the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice  (and  indeed  sometimes
 necessary  under  Linux)  to  put  an fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation between
 write and read operations on such a stream.  This operation may be an apparent
 no-op  (as  in  fseek(...,  0L,  SEEK_CUR)  called  for its synchronizing side
 effect.'

ftell is likely treated as a read operation. Try inserting fseek(...,  0L,  SEEK_CUR) before ftell and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not locking the file before you open it, it is not thread-safe.

Any other process could open the file for I/O with unpredictable results.

Comment: I'm interested in the thread safety of the code -- not whether it's protected against some other separate process writing to the same file, which I know is not happening.

Comment: Maybe not now, but you can never be certain how a program will develop over time; failing to lock a file in a system that is designed to have an element of concurrency has a high probability of biting you at a later date.

Comment: Understood. I appreciate that, but it doesn't address the issue I'm seeing now.